# Seeking a reference explicitly displaying the Lorentz factor in the context of Schwarzschild geodesics

Tags: general-relativity, reference-frames, energy-conservation, coordinate-systems, resource-recommendations

I am searching for a reference that explicitly displays the content of FIG. 1 (especially, the following equation) mentioned on the [Wikipedia site](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_geodesics#Local_and_delayed_velocities) to use as a citation:

$$E = mc^2 \sqrt{\frac{1-r_s/r}{1-v^2/c^2}}. $$

For context, this equation pertains to the energy representation for the Schwarzschild system in General Relativity, involving the Lorentz factor.

As an example, I have looked into Hartle's textbook, which provides the content shown in FIG. 2.

However, it does not explicitly display the Lorentz factor, making it unsatisfactory for my needs.

Does anyone know of a document or paper that explicitly expresses the Lorentz factor in this context? I would greatly appreciate any relevant information.

---

- FIG. 1

[image: Energy representation for the Schwarzschild system in General Relativity]

---

- FIG. 2  [James B. Hartle, Gravity: An introduction to Einstein's General Relativity, Chapter 9.3, p.193]

[image: FIG.2]

Comment: Please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563/168783), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/479421) instead.

Comment: A few lines above where your quote of the wikipedia article begins, it defines the time dilation factor $\frac{d\tau}{dt}$.  Using that definition you can arrive at Hartle's expression.  You can probably find a similar definition of $\frac{dt}{d\tau}$ in Hartle's book.  It may be written in terms of the $t$-component of the 4-velocity, $u^0$ (or something similar), which is probably expressed in terms of $\gamma$ in an introductory chapter on S.R.